# why restarting reverts the version of node

Tags: node.js, macos, nvm

I've installed node version 5.8 and used

```
nvm alias default 5.8
```

to make it default version of node. then I changed the current version of node using

```
nvm use 5.8
```

Why every time I turn off the system, default version of node becomes v0.10.30?

**More context:**
I need to use

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

every time too. otherwise `nvm` is not recognized.

Comment: Do you have $NVM_DIR defined in your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: Also, how was `nvm` installed? `curl`, or `homebrew` ?

Comment: @gnerkus I didn't want to combine questions so I didn't mention it. I need to use `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` every time too. otherwise `nvm` is not recognized

Comment: @gnerkus I've installed nvm as in it's readme using curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because `nvm` is not loaded with each new terminal session. As a result, the default Node version is not persisted.

You can load `nvm` for each terminal session by adding these lines to your `.bashrc` file:

```
export NVM_DIR="/Users/gnerkus/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Comment: I'm using OSX El Capitan and it worked for me with ~/.profile file instead of ~/.bashrc. Thank you